# Run only R commands in rmd file

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown

I have a large Markdown file (*.Rmd) and want to execute only the R commands in that file (not the text) in RStudio. How can this be done?

If I mark the whole document and try to execute it, R tries to execute also the text in the Markdown file, which, of course, results in errors.

Comment: If you just need to run all the chunks in the rmd file you can do this by Command + Option + R or Command + A + Enter on a Mac; Ctrl + Alt + R or Ctrl + A + Enter on Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Click on the arrows at the top right of the chunks:

[image]